# Launch an application in background- Launch Service in background to copy sms content into db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent

I am trying to develop an application that allows you to save a SQLite database of SMS on the phone as they arrive. I am using the broadcast receiver to recover the message then the activity component to insert into the database. But I'd replace activity by service for the application does not bother the user. Does anyone want to help me.Here is my code://

> MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private final String ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        @Override

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RECEIVE_SMS)) {

                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

                if (bundle != null) {

                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                    SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {

                        message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    }

                    if (message.length > -1) {

                        String messageBody = message[0].getMessageBody();

                        String phoneNumber = message[0].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Expediteur - numero :" + phoneNumber + " Sms : " + messageBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Intent SecondeItent = new Intent(context, SmsActivity.class);

                        SecondeItent.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);

                        SecondeItent.putExtra("messageBody", messageBody);

                        SecondeItent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                        context.startActivity(SecondeItent);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SmsActivity extends Activity {

        smsdao.open();

        smsdao.insertSms(sms);

        Sms smsFromBdd = smsdao.getSmsWithNum(sms.getNum());

        if (smsFromBdd != null) {

            Toast.makeText(this, sms FromBdd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        smsdao.close();
    }
    }
```

Other file: SmsDao.java,MyBaseSQLite.java, Sms.java et AndroidManifest.xml, but there are no problems on these files.

Comment: Pls format your code. Its so difficult to understand whats in there.

Comment: Use `Service` for this purpose.

Comment: if you want to Launch your application in Background then use Service...

Answer (score 0):

**A sample service**

```
   public class MainService extends Service {

    public MainService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // your logic

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

**Invoking service**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
    startService(intent);
```

**manifest**

```
<service android:name="packageName.MainService" >
    </service>
```